# AWS Toolkit for Eclipse : Running AwsConsoleApp issue?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, amazon-web-services, cloudera, ganglia

I'm new to AWS, When I try to run AwsConsoleApp.java in eclipse, I'm getting the following error. I have set the access-id and secret-key properly.

```
===========================================
    Welcome to the AWS Java SDK!
    ===========================================
    Caught Exception: Request has expired. Timestamp date is 2013-07-09T06:24:57.628Z
    Reponse Status Code: 400
    Error Code: RequestExpired
    Request ID: xxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx
    Caught Exception: Request has expired. Timestamp date is 2013-07-09T06:25:00.216Z. Current date is 2013-07-22T07:27:27Z
    Reponse Status Code: 400
    Error Code: RequestExpired
    Request ID: xxxxx--xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx
    Error Message:    The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.
    HTTP Status Code: 403
    AWS Error Code:   RequestTimeTooSkewed
    Error Type:       Client
    Request ID:       xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Thanks in advance and Can anyone tell me what change to be made to run properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your time stamp in your local machine. As well as that matches the server instance time stamp. Both time stamp should be same, then only it will work properly.

Comment: Thanks alot @sasi It worked after I made changes as you said.